# $scope of Same Controller when changing Location Path

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this two pages index.html#/view and index.html#/update (view and update are also html files)

Their layout is essentially the same (except that `view` is for viewing only and `update` is for editing), they use same directives, `search-div` with search-div.html as template and `result-div` with result-div.html
and a common controller `PageCtrl`

search-div.html

```
<div>
    <form>
        <input ng-model="page.id">
        <input ng-model="page.type">
        <button ng-click="page.cancel()">Cancel</button>
        <button ng-click="page.submit()">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

result-div.html

```
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>...</thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>{{page.retrievedData.id}}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>{{page.retrievedData.type}}</td></tr>
            // some other retrieved data as rows
            // some rows are, for view <td>, for update <input>
    <table>
</div>
```

`result-div` is obtained by some `$http.get`.

view.html

```
<div ng-controller="PageCtrl as page">
    <search-div></search-div>
    <result-div></result-div>
    <button ng-click="page.modify('update', page.id, page.type)">Modify</button>
</div>
```

update.html

```
<div ng-controller="PageCtrl as page">
    <search-div></search-div>
    <result-div></result-div>
    <button ng-click="page.save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

When I click the `modify` button, the `id` and `type` in the `search-div` of `view` page should still show on `update` page, so I did:

(inside PageCtrl)

```
$scope.modify = function(path, id, type) {
    $location.path(path);
    $scope.id = id;
    $scope.type = type;
};
```

There was no problem with re-directing to another page, however, the `id` and `type` does not reflect in `update`'s `search-div`. What happens to the `$scope` from `view` to `update` directive? How can I properly pass the values of `view` `$scope` to `update` `$scope`? I would also like to know how to show `result-div` in `update` page with the same result from `view` page.

Comment: In your `modify` function you accept `id` and `type` but you use `deviceId` and `deviceType` instead. I think you intended to use the parameters.

Comment: Sorry, that's just a typo error in copying and pasting. I corrected it. Same problem though.

Comment: Try to set `id` and `type` and then redirect.

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan Nope, didn't work. Still redirecting with `input` fields' empty.

Comment: You'll need to create a [service][1] to pass the data across views. When moving from between views you'll be disposing the previous controlller.


  [1]: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services